# Trying to append new rows to an ongoing spreadsheet using a function in R

Tags: html, r, excel, web-scraping, xlsx

I've been using the `write.xlsx` function to append new rows of data that I pull in via a `HTML scrapper`. For some reason though instead of pulling in the information from one `url` pasting it in the sheet and moving on to the next one it just paste the last `url` I put in the function.

I've tried writing a `for loop` in the actual code, getting rid of the `for loop` and calling the function for each individual `url` and putting the `url`s into a `vector` and using the `lapply` function on the vector. All of these methods "work" but have the same result.

```
urlpull <- function(site){
url <- site
webpage <- read_html(url)
tbls <- webpage %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table(header = FALSE, fill = TRUE) 
tbls <- tbls %>% lmap( ~ set_names(.x, nm = pluck(.x, 1, 1, 1))) %>% map(~ set_names(.x, nm = .x[2, ]))
abbr <- as.data.frame(webpage %>% html_nodes('strong') %>% html_text() %>% .[5:6])
rec <- as.data.frame(webpage %>% html_nodes('div') %>% html_text() %>% .[c(26,33)])
date <- as.data.frame(webpage %>% html_nodes('div') %>% html_text() %>% .[36])
awaybas <- tbls %>% .[1]
awayadv <- tbls %>% .[2] 
homebas <- tbls %>% .[3] 
homeadv <- tbls %>% .[4] 
ab1 <- as.data.frame(awaybas)
aa1 <- as.data.frame(awayadv)
hb1 <- as.data.frame(homebas)
ha1 <- as.data.frame(homeadv)
ab <- ab1[-c(1,2,8),]
aa <- aa1[-c(1,2,8),]
hb <- hb1[-c(1,2,8),]
ha <- ha1[-c(1,2,8),]
ab[,c(3:21)] <- sapply(ab[,c(3:21)], as.numeric)
aa[,c(3:16)] <- sapply(aa[,c(3:16)], as.numeric)
hb[,c(3:21)] <- sapply(hb[,c(3:21)], as.numeric)
ha[,c(3:16)] <- sapply(ha[,c(3:16)], as.numeric)
aa <- cbind(aa, abbr[1,], abbr[2,])
ab <- cbind(ab, abbr[1,], abbr[2,])
hb <- cbind(hb, abbr[2,], abbr[1,])
ha <- cbind(ha, abbr[2,], abbr[1,])
aa <- cbind(aa, rec[1,])
ab <- cbind(ab, rec[1,])
hb <- cbind(hb, rec[2,])
ha <- cbind(ha, rec[2,])
aa <- cbind(aa, date)
ab <- cbind(ab, date)
hb <- cbind(hb, date)
ha <- cbind(ha, date)
names(aa)[17:20]<-c("TEAM", "OPP", "RCRD", "DT")
names(ab)[22:25]<-c("TEAM", "OPP", "RCRD", "DT")
names(hb)[22:25]<-c("TEAM", "OPP", "RCRD", "DT")
names(ha)[17:20]<-c("TEAM", "OPP", "RCRD", "DT")
aa <- aa %>% separate("MP", c("min","sec"), sep = ":") %>% separate("RCRD", c("W","L"), sep= "-") %>% separate("DT", c("time", "day", "year"), sep = ",") %>% unite(DT, c("day", "year", "time"), sep = ",") %>% mutate(DT = mdy_hm(DT))
ab <- ab %>% separate("MP", c("min","sec"), sep = ":") %>% separate("RCRD", c("W","L"), sep= "-") %>% separate("DT", c("time", "day", "year"), sep = ",") %>% unite(DT, c("day", "year", "time"), sep = ",") %>% mutate(DT = mdy_hm(DT))
hb <- hb %>% separate("MP", c("min","sec"), sep = ":") %>% separate("RCRD", c("W","L"), sep= "-") %>% separate("DT", c("time", "day", "year"), sep = ",") %>% unite(DT, c("day", "year", "time"), sep = ",") %>% mutate(DT = mdy_hm(DT))
ha <- ha %>% separate("MP", c("min","sec"), sep = ":") %>% separate("RCRD", c("W","L"), sep= "-") %>% separate("DT", c("time", "day", "year"), sep = ",") %>% unite(DT, c("day", "year", "time"), sep = ",") %>% mutate(DT = mdy_hm(DT))
aa[,c(20:21)] <- sapply(aa[,c(20:21)], as.numeric)
ab[,c(25:26)] <- sapply(ab[,c(25:26)], as.numeric)
hb[,c(25:26)] <- sapply(hb[,c(25:26)], as.numeric)
ha[,c(20:21)] <- sapply(ha[,c(20:21)], as.numeric)
aa <- aa %>% mutate(GAME = W + L)
ab <- ab %>% mutate(GAME = W + L)
hb <- hb %>% mutate(GAME = W + L)
ha <- ha %>% mutate(GAME = W + L)
aac <- aa[,-c(1:3)]
hac <- ha[,-c(1:3)]
am <- cbind(ab[,-c(23:28)],aac)
hm <- cbind(hb[,-c(23:28)],hac)
am <- am %>% mutate(LOCAL = "away")
hm <- hm %>% mutate(LOCAL = "home")
final <- rbind(am,hm)
print(final)
write.xlsx(final, "Book1.xlsx", sheetName= "Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, showNA= TRUE)
}
```

```
x <- c("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201410280LAL.html",     "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201811140BRK.html")

lapply(x, urlpull)
```

I just want the final table from the output to be placed on the first row after the last table was placed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this problem I kept the for loop and had the function row bind all the dataframes into one, before exporting it out. I did this by initiating a empty dataframe outside the for loop like this:

```
oldtable <- data.frame()

for (i in x) {

  #Generic lines of code

  final          #table from one iteration of loop
  oldtable <- rbind.data.frame(oldtable, final)
}
```

Using the rbind.data.frame function from base R got the results that I previously wanted.